# How to create multiple file upload button with add and remove button in angular?

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular12, ng-file-upload, jquery-upload-file-plugin

My question is how to create a new file upload button/input with add and remove button in Angular 12. we should be able to add as many upload button/input we want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ngx dropzone. Using ngx dropzone you can add or drag and drop multiple files in a single time.For using this u can follow the steps in the following link.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dropzone